# find complexity for a code

Tags: c, queue, analysis, time-complexity

Consider the following operation along with Enqueue and Dequeue operations on queues, where k is a global parameter

```
MultiDequeue ( Q )
{
  m=k
  while ( Q is not empty ) and (m > 0 ) 
  {
    Dequeue ( Q )
    m = m −1
  }
}
```

What is the worst case time complexity of a sequence of n queue operations on an initially empty queue? (A) Θ (n) (B) Θ (n + k ) (C) Θ (nk )

its not my homework it was asked to me in my exam......n according to me it shoud be (n + k).

it cant be (n) because there is an and condition in while loop so it is dependent on both n and k....and since it is not a nested loop or some matrix it is not (nk)....

i solved it this way if while ( Q is not empty ) was there instead of while ( Q is not empty ) and (m > 0 ) then time complexity would have been (n) and if m = 4 it should be n+k instead of nk.....it really was a guess actually

Comment: Seems GATE question...

Comment: lolz... right different coaching institutes are telling different answers for this and BTW how was ur xam

Comment: I have passed Mtech bt still appeared for it...was ok..!!

Comment: good for u bro...any idea about cutoff this time

Comment: It will be around 30..it is increasing annually..

Comment: but it was tough like hell this time anyway i am screwed

Comment: Are you counting some sort of population as part of the operations order, because if not, and the queue is initially empty (as stated) going in to the posted algorithm, this is somewhat pointless.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what order of n Enqueue, Dequeue or MultiDequeue is the number of primitive O(1) operations Enqueue/Dequeue cannot exceed 2*n. So it is O(n).

Comment: I concur. I came up with `k` always being irrelevant, since it can have no effect beyond `n`. For an arbitrarily enormous `k` and a fixed `n`, then `k-n` is ignored leaving just `n+n`, therefore deducing to at-worst 2*n, therefore O(n).

Answer (score 1):

The queue is empty initially, so the condition of the while loop will never become true, so the time complexity will be Theta(n).
Or other way, if only enquque and dequeue operations are performed, then it'll be also Theta(n)(n insertions and n deletions).

Answer (score -3):

Answer is C. In worst case you will be performing n Enqueue operations.